# C# - Try/Catch with predicate expression

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The following is an example taken from [MSDN, try-catch (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

```
catch (ArgumentException e) if (e.ParamName == "…")
{
}
```

They also say

> Using catch arguments is one way to filter for the exceptions you want to handle. You can also use a predicate expression that further examines the exception to decide whether to handle it. If the predicate expression returns false, then the search for a handler continues.
>
> Exception filters are preferable to catching and rethrowing (explained below) because filters leave the stack unharmed. If a later handler dumps the stack, you can see where the exception originally came from, rather than just the last place it was rethrown. A common use of exception filter expressions is logging. You can create a predicate function that always returns false that also outputs to a log, you can log exceptions as they go by without having to handle them and rethrow.

My code:

```
static bool LogFunction(System.Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Writing to logfile: {0}", ex.Message);
    return false;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("The exception message...");
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex) if (LogFunction(ex))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("This will not be executed, ever!");
    }
    catch(System.ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler won't compile this (csc.exe), giving the following error message:

```
error CS1003: Syntax error, 'when' expected
```

Edit: The compiler raises the error for the line

```
error CS1003: Syntax error, 'when' expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT: I submitted feedback to MSDN pointing out the error in the documentation.**

Comment: The catch filter logic is only available as part of VS2015. Is this the version you are using?

Comment: As far as I remember this if was replaced with 'when' keyword try to swap if to when

Comment: I am compiling via 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2015', so yeah. I have Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` be replaced with the word `when` instead?

Comment: Documentation bugs for the win!

Comment: Yeah, it was an error in the documentation.

Comment: hmm. the error is also obvious ;)

Comment: The documentation also has `catch` with an upper case C. Please flag it on MSDN by using the Any Suggestions feature.

Comment: Update: The documentation hasn't been corrected yet...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's an error on the MSDN site. As the compiler suggests, you should use `when` instead of `if`.

Comment: Is there a language spec available for a version of c# that has this feature?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I guess someone should point it out to the MSDN guys.

Comment: @recursive It seems the latest version of the spec is for C# 5.0

Comment: @recursive Jakub is right, 5.0 was the last formal version, the 6.0 "spec" seems to be buried in the Roslyn project page in the form of roadmaps, features, and tickets.